Entrega de HTML API MINIMA ASP.NET error email
Queria consultar sobre la forma de entregar HTML, en ASP.NET Core.
Actualmente estoy en una API minima, en un ENDPOINT el cual recibe por parametro un token aleatorio enviado a traves de un EMAIL de confirmacion. Esto es para confirmar la creacion de la cuenta de usuario. Si el token existe y es valido, realiza el proceso correspondiente, y luego unicamente devuelve una simple web que dice "Cuenta confirmada" o "Enlace de confirmacion expirado"
    app.MapGet("/Sda/ConfirmAccount/{token}", (HttpContext context, string token) => {
        if (AccountDatabase.ExistsAccoutToken(token) == true) { 
Console.WriteLine("registro exitoso");
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/HTML";
            context.Response.SendFileAsync("wwwroot/confirmed.html");  }
        else { 
    
            Console.WriteLine("Intento de confirmacion con token expirado");
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/HTML";
            context.Response.SendFileAsync("wwwroot/expired.html");
        }
    });

NO tengo inconveniente con el proceso interno que se realiza cuando se recibe la peticion. El problema lo tengo con la entrega del HTML.
En este momento realizo las pruebas de modo local, y el HTML se muestra correctamente. Pero cuando hago pruebas con la API publicada, la subo al servidor el proceso se ejecuta correctamente, pero el enlace enviado por correo NO muestra el HTML. Queda la pagina en blanco.
El problema lo tenia en MOBILE, pero acabo de probar en PC y ocurre lo mismo. Ahora bien, si hago pruebas en local, en desarrollo , se muestra correctamente. Cuando lo subo al servidor , se presenta el problema.
El servidor tiene SSL, asi que las paginas van con conexiones seguras.
Sinceramente hay veces que context.Response.SendFileAsync me envia el texto HTML en vez de mostrar la web . Y hay veces que no. Aveces debo agregarle CONTENT TYPE para que funcione, aveces , ni siquiera es necesario.
Como soy novato en esto de las API, quiza no sea la mejor manera de entregar HTML al cliente.

Porque devolves un HTML, en lugar de redirigirlo al HTML que queres?? si ese HTML es estatico, no tiene mucho sentido devolverlo...

Buenas. Bueno hay conceptos que no tengo del todo claros. Probare con una redireccion. Pero de todas maneras esta parte del frontend la entrego desde la API. Es decir, la api se encarga de entregar o servir estos archivos. Si redirecciono a otro endpoint de la misma API, no deberia hacer lo mismo para entregar ese HTML ?  Este html no esta en un servidor web aparte, si no que es parte de la API, q se encarga de entregar estos archivos.

Ese html es un endpoint que solo tiene un html dentro de tu servidor. Si vos hicieras http://tuweb/esehtml deberia servirlo, con lo cual, si le decis al front que la respuesta es un redirect a esa url, el front va a pedir ese html y lo va a servir sin mas...

Okey, bueno algo pude solucionar de esa manera. Pero de todas formas hay algo que no entiendo. Cuando se accede a mi ENDPOINT base, yo entrego el html basico de login de esta manera con SendFileAsync. Cuando el navegador accede, se le entrega ese HTML. Porque desde el email, cuando se linkea, el html aparece vacio? Es un problema de rutas ? o un problema de seguridad . Creo que me estoy dando cuenta que es un problema de rutas. Porque mi URL dentro del link que envio por MAIL, va con un token aleatorio. Aunque no estoy seguro.

Es que no entiendo pq tu endpoint sirve htmls.. si de los html se encargar el servidor web.. tu api debe servir datos, no htmls...

Todavia estoy adentrandome en esto de las APIS. Entiendo que lo ideal seria que todo el frontend este separado en el server web y la API solo entregue los datos. Pero como soy nuevo con asp.  Estube realizando cada proyecto con su propio frontend. Es decir, hice el frontend, lo agregue a la carpeta wwwroot y hago que cada proyecto entregue su propio front.  Entiendo que con api minima esto no deberia ser asi.

Configure un NGINX que inverso, para que apunte cada solicitud a cada proyecto ASP NET. Y que cada proyecto entregue su propio front. El asunto es que , sobretodo en esta API, queria tener el control de lo que visita el cliente. Sin que sea accesible directamente desde la URL. De todas maneras ,tengo verdes muchos conceptos.

Quiza trabajar con un renderizado lado servidor seria lo que necesito. Pero estoy aprendiendo ASP al reves. Empeze con api minimas, luego con controladores, y todavia toque poco de razor, y esas cosas.

Me parece que tenes que mirar al reves, porque estas complejizando una tarea que es mucho mas simple.. ;)

Entiendo. En si, lo que yo intento hacer con eso de alguna manera es evitar que se acceda a la pagina de Login directamente desde cualquier lado. Hay otra app, que se comunica con la app de autenticacion, y si esta app esta registrada con la app de autenticacion , se genera una ruta aleatoria y si la misma es valida, se entrega ese HTML de login. En cambio de esta manera el frontend es accesible desde cualquier lado. Seguro no es el enfoque adecuado. Pero sera cuestion de entender bien los conceptos.

Y que problema hay que se acceda? lo raro es eso.. que necesites un token aleatorio para llegar a una pagina.. Todo eso complejiza la app.. Si lo pienso de otra forma, seguis con el mismo problema, porque podrias ir a una landing que chequeara ese aleatorio y que luego tu back seteara una cokkie para poder entrar a la otra.. todo eso que me decis, en general, no se controla por la app... inclusive cuando haces un recovery de pass, con rutas aleatorias, la ruta es estatica, y el back controla que el token generado en esa ruta sea valido por otros medios...

Hola de nuevo!! Bueno como te digo!! Todo voy aprendiendo de apoco. Justamente esta api, es una api de autentication basica que estaba diseñando. Y mi idea era añadirle una capa de seguridad extra, como para que si alguien accede o tiene la URL del endpoint, no pueda estar pegandole al punto de entrada. El token aleatorio lo genero yo, si la aplicacion que intenta hacer uso de este servicio, tiene las credenciales correctas.  Haber es una forma que se me ocurrio agregar para la seguridad. Pero no se si es la manera correcta.

Me explico.  Seguramente que hay otras formas de hacerlo. O de aumentar la seguridad.  Por el momento con mi conocimiento se me ocurrio esta forma. Mi idea es que la api , no pueda ser accedida por nadie , si no es atraves de otra api.   Luego una vez que la APP esta registrada se le da un endpoint valido digamos, y recien ahi entrega la interfaz de autenticacion junto con las rutas que reciben los datos. Despues la api internamente genera el BEARER y se lo devuelve nuevamente a la API que lo solicito.

Pienso que entregar rutas aleatorias podria o puede ayudar con la seguridad como una medida adicional. Ahora si se pueden escanear estas rutas ya escapa de mi conocimiento.

Tus ideas, ya estan todas inventadas y por otros metodos mucho mas automaticos. Si es una API minima, justamente, lo que deberia hacer es minimo.. esto no suena a minimo... Las url aleatorias no se usan para login, se usan para recuperar mails. Para login, siempre vas al mismo lugar. De igual forma, no se le pega a una api, se le pega a una url... Creo que tenes buenas intenciones, pero todo lo que me estas diciendo ya esta inventado y no se hace asi.. te invito al [chat] si queres seguir la charla.
